# Docker container running SQL Server exits on start

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm running an instance of SQL Server in a Docker container. It exits on start automatically. The logs say:

```
SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
Your master database file is owned by mssql.
To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
sqlservr: Unable to read instance id from /var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id: File: pal.cpp:438 [Status: 0xC0000034 Object name not found errno = 0x2(2) No such file or directory]
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: PAL initialization failed. Error: 101
```

If I am reading this right SQL Server will not run with root user. But then both my container and volume are running as the same non-root user. So I'm confused where the problem is coming from. Can someone help me decode this error message?

Comment: I have to little info, missing docker file, missing docker run command. Check out this repo with lot's of examples running sql server in docker: https://github.com/enriquecatala/mssql-server-samplesdb

Comment: In prior versions of SQL Server for Docker the SQL Server process did run as `root`, but since about 2019 they now abide by the Least Privilege principle and run with a specific `mssql` user. Given the "No such file or directory" error message, have you changed the Docker volumes/mounts on the container recently?

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue today. It happened after I resized disk partition somehow.

At first I inspected docker volume and data seemed to be ok, however

```
/var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id
```

wich is

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/[YOUR-VOLUME]/_data/.system/instance_id
```

**was empty!**

Then I googled this thread https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/615 suggested to run `chown 10001:0` on _data folder wich did not help.

Fortunately my docker is running inside Hyper-V vm. So I created checkpoint and  reverted to previous one to see whats inside `instance_id` file

It turned out to be guid and 20 digit number

```
dfb10ba0-dc20-4022-ab31-0f52be4dcabe
16537894658124376490
```

I copied that and returned to latest checkpoint. Stopped container, updated `instance_id` with recovered data and container started seamlessly.

> SQL Server on Linux stores the sequential UUID seed in
> /var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id and increments it during startup.
> Take a backup of the instance_id file in case of system failure. If
> the file is lost, the seed is missing, and the new seed is
> regenerated. The initial seed generation is based on a random bit
> pattern and a UUID to avoid collisions. However, the new seed that has
> to be sequentially ordered may not be sequentially ordered after the
> seed is lost.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4078097-fix-newsequentialid-function-generates-duplicate-guid-after-sql-server-2017-on-linux-is-restarted-829b97f7-6359-8f66-6581-37aac819c210

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused by binding the sql server volume `/var/opt/mssql` in the wrong way.

E.g.

```
docker run `
    --name sqlexpress `
    -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y `
    -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD="averyuRandomPass0wrd" `
    -p 1433:1433 `
    -v "/var/lib/docker/mssql:/var/opt/mssql" `
    -e MSSQL_PID="Express" `
    -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
```

Instead, ensure to map subvolumes of `/var/opt/mssql`

```
docker run `
    --name sqlexpress `
    -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y `
    -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD="averyuRandomPass0wrd" `
    -p 1433:1433 `
    -v "/var/lib/docker/mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql/data" `
    -v "/var/lib/docker/mssql/log:/var/opt/mssql/log" `
    -e MSSQL_PID="Express" `
    -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
```

A bit more detail on the problem https://www.herlitz.io/2022/12/22/sql-server-in-docker---palinstanceid-unable-to-read-instance-id-from-file/